# Good or not question about Android mini game

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Is this question "too broad" or otherwise not a good fit for the site?

> If I start a new Android mini game project today, is it a good idea to
>   use (and learn) Kotlin if I already know Java and I already have quite
>   a lot of Android boilerplate re-usable game code in Java?
>
> I had a new idea and we have now decided for a name of the game. It
>   will be a small aircraft which the player will maneuver in 2D and
>   side-scrolling. To begin with I want to create it for Android. I am
>   considering doing it in Kotlin because that it the new preferred
>   language for Android, or maybe Unity engine.
>
> (React-native or Flutter are not good choices for game development if
>   I understand correctly.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking here!

It is off-topic, "what technology to use", as described in the [help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Sorry for the brevity, I'm on my phone.